# How to correct input validation for array?

Tags: python, arrays, validation

I was just wondering if there was a way so that

```
def main():
    SIZE = 7
    people = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
    #phoneNumbers = ['1231111111', '1232222222', '1233333333', '1234444444', '1235555555', '1236666666', '1237777777'] 

    # name validation
    index = 0
    nameInput = input("Enter a person's name: ")
    while (nameInput.lower() != people[index]):
        if (nameInput.lower() == people[index]):
            input("Error: Please enter a name: ")
        else:
            index = index + 1

    # find the name
    found = False
    index = 0
    while (found == False and index <= SIZE - 1):
        if (people[index] == nameInput.lower()):
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1
    
    if found:
        print("The person's name and phone number is:", people[index], index + 1)
    else:
        print('No user found at ', index + 1)
    
main()
```

would print an error and ask for reinput upon the error and have this iterate

> input("Error: Please enter a name: ")

Or I guess my main goal would be so that it'll cycle through the list of names and make sure the name validation goes through

Things I've tried:

1. Setting the conditions and trying to find which condition would allow that
2. Deleting the if portion nested in the while statement, but gets rid of the resulting code that shows which place the names are, and only allows "bob" to work

Pardon for the messy code, writing this atm

Comment: Are you trying to get as input from the user a name, then check if that name is in your list and then if it isn't throw an error and ask for reinput?

Comment: yes @Filip im asking for that exactly, my bad for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do and more information would be great, but it sounds like a dictionary would be the perfect data structure, because it is easier to implement and fast to parse. For example if you had three people, say "Emily", "Bob" and "John", then you could assign their names to their phone numbers.

```py
# Parallel lists, each index of one list corresponds to the same index of the other list
people = ["bob", "emily", "john"]
phones = ["123", "124", "125"]

people_dict = {}
for i in range(len(people)):
    people_dict[people[i]] = phones[i]

print(people_dict)  # prints "{'bob': '123', 'emily': '124', 'john': '125'}"

while True:
    in_name = input("Person's name: ")
    try:
        print(f"{in_name}'s phone number is: {people_dict[in_name]}")
        break
    except KeyError:
        print("The name you provided was not in the list\nPlease retry.\n")
```

This should work then. Easy enough and faster than looping in a list. The `for` loop I used was just to create the dictionary. Also to create the dictionary this way, there have to be the same number of people and phone numbers, or the program will exit with an `IndexError` inside the `for` loop.

---

If you had to use lists, you could still try to find the index of a name and if it is not found, retry.

```py
# Parallel lists, each index of one list corresponds to the same index of the other list
people = ["bob", "emily", "john"]
phones = ["123", "124", "125"]

while True:
    in_name = input("Person's name: ")
    try:
        print(f"{in_name}'s phone number is {phones[people.index(in_name)]}")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("The name you provided was not in the list\nPlease retry.\n")
```

Comment: this is the idea what I had in mind going to this, and my bad for the lack of info on this.  I was just trying to make it so then the names in the list would be read with a loop and then I'd be able to tell them that the info is wrong if the wrong name was implemented and to ask for the input again like how you've done, although its never really occured to me about any of this stuff, break, keyerror, and except

Answer (score 0):

```
    people = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
    phoneNumbers = ['1231111111', '1232222222', '1233333333', '1234444444', '1235555555', '1236666666', '1237777777'] 
    index = None
    while index is None:
        nameInput = input("Enter a person's name: ")
        if nameInput in people:
            index = phoneNumbers.index(nameInput)
            print("The person's name and phone number is:", people[index], phoneNumbers[index], index + 1)
        else:
            print('No user found')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    SIZE = 7
    people = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
    phoneNumbers = ['121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127']

    
    nameInput = input("Enter a person's name: ")

    # find the name and phone number
    found = False
    index = 0
    while (found == False and index <= SIZE - 1):
        if (people[index] == nameInput.lower()):
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1
    if found:
        print("The person's name and phone number is:", people[index], phoneNumbers[index])
    else:
        print('No user found')

# call main to run    
main()
```

well i guess i got it to work

Thanks for those who pitched in an answer